# Как правильно сделать binding WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding

я хочу чтобы работали кнопки CheckEdit
делаю биндинг через проперти MyProperty данные виводяться хорошо, но мне еще нужно чтобы `IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsChecked}"` работал. Я сделал проперти, но почему то не работает, как исправить ?

XAML

```
 <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyProperty}" Margin="0"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="1" >
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <dxe:CheckEdit Content="{Binding}" Padding="2.5" Margin="3" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsChecked}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical"  />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
```

C#

```
List<string> arrayList = new List<string>();

        foreach (DataText item in DataT)
        {
            bool exists = false;

            foreach (var it in types)
            {
                if (it == item.TypeFiles)
                {
                    arrayList.Add(item.TypeFiles);

                    Items.Add(new MyCheckBox(item.TypeFiles, IsChecked));
                }
            }
        }

        uniqueList = new List<string>(arrayList.Distinct());

        MyProperty = uniqueList;


    }

    private bool? _isChecked = null;

    public bool? IsChecked
    {
        get { return _isChecked; }

        set
        {
            _isChecked = value;
            OnPropertyChange("IsChecked");
        }
    }


    public List<string> MyProperty
    {
        get
        { return uniqueList; }
        set
        {
            uniqueList = value;
            OnPropertyChange("MyProperty");
        }
    }
```

Comment: а что если такой binding: `IsChecked="{Binding DataContext.IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}`?

Comment: нет так тоже не работает

Comment: ну binding в Вашем коде совершенно точно работать не будет, т.к. Вы используете property из DataContext, который установлен для `ItemsControl`, но для `ItemsControl.ItemTemplate` DateContext устанавливается в элементы списка, который установлен в `ItemsSource`, т.е. для вашего случая это `MyProperty`. Чтобы починить binding, Вам надо поиграться с `RelativeSource` и `Ancestor`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я сделал класс, в который поместил название и `isChecked`, и динамически его выгрузил с массива:

```
    public bool? IsChecked { get; set; }
    public string FilePath { get; set; }


    public MyCheckBox(string FilePath, bool? IsChecked)
    {
        this.FilePath = FilePath;
        this.IsChecked = IsChecked;
    } TempList = new List<MyCheckBox>();

        foreach (var type in tempUniqueList)
        {
            TempList.Add(new MyCheckBox(type, true));
        }

        MyProperty = TempList;
```

XAML

```
<DataTemplate>
    <dxe:CheckEdit Content="{Binding FilePath, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Padding="2.5" Margin="3"  IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1):

По умолчанию режим связывания однонаправленный, Вы можете установить `Mode = TwoWay` вручную https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.data.binding.mode(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: я уже пробовал так делать, все без изминений